# Generate an Image from a Map in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, apple-maps

Here's what I want to do:

1. Get some destination.
2. Render it in the maps into a view.
3. Turn that into an image I can then save and use as a background.

Another option would be to put a map view down, turn off all input and just paint on top of it. Basically asking for a way to rasterize the map view. Wondering if anyone has done this.

Answer (score 4):

You can render any view into an image with something like this:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: On a retina device, I'd use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.bounds.size, NO, 0.f)`

Comment: @followben, yeah, that is the newer and better way to do it. I updated to change to this.